# Word for arrangement of playing cards

Tags: word-request

Is there a word for the cascaded arrangement of playing cards; i.e. the way players hold them in their hands in the form of flower petals? An example would be [this image](https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/playing-cards-15925542.jpg).

Comment: It's called a fan. When done on a table, it's called a spread.

Comment: @MickSharpe: Thanks. Why didn't you post it as answer?

Comment: There may be other usages. I'm no expert. My reticence comes from other forums where people jump on you if you don't get it exactly right. However, people are more relaxed here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called a fan. When done on a table, it's called a spread. Note that some card players call it a spread even if it's held in the hand. Also, both words can be used as verbs as well as nouns.

Comment: Well done @MickSharpe. Beware, though: there are bridge players here, and they are fearsome.